# Retrieving resolution of an image and print along with it

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a custom php code to print a list of images in drupal. Here is my code for this functionality.

```
<?php
$dir = drupal_get_path('module', 'cproduct') . '/tdesignAPI/images  
 /Images';

$files1 = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files1 as $value) {
    if (strpos($value,'.png') !== false) {

    $p3 = drupal_get_path('module', 'cproduct') . '/tdesignAPI/images/Images/';?>

    <div class="sample_icons"><img src="<?php echo $p3 .$value;?>" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
    <?php 
    }
    elseif(strpos($value,'.') === false) {
    //echo '<div class="sample_icons"><img src="tdesignAPI/images/folder.png" width="100%" height="100%" />' .$value. '</div>' ;
    }
        //echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
 }
 ?>
```

My requirement is to retrieve the resolution or size of the images listed and print it with each image. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getimagesize()` function.

Try

```
foreach ($files1 as $value)
{
    if (strpos($value,'.png') !== false)
    {
        $image_resolution = getimagesize($dir.$value);
        $image_resolution = $image_resolution[3];

    $p3 = drupal_get_path('module', 'cproduct') . '/tdesignAPI/images/Images/';
    ?>
        <div class="sample_icons"><img src="<?php echo $p3 .$value;?>" <?php echo $image_resolution?> /></div>
    <?php 
    }
    elseif(strpos($value,'.') === false)
    {
    //echo '<div class="sample_icons"><img src="tdesignAPI/images/folder.png" width="100%" height="100%" />' .$value. '</div>' ;
    }
        //echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the sudden reply Hassan. Its almost there. I have followed your method and there is a small error which is                              Warning: getimagesize(sites/all/modules/cproduct/tdesignAPI/images/Imagesjavelin_throw.png) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 273 of /var/www/divya/custom_product/sites/all/modules/cproduct/tdesignAPI/new_applit.php). I am getting this error for all the images i have listed.

Comment: @AbyBasheer actually you image path is not correct. is `sites/all/modules/cproduct/tdesignAPI/images/Imagesjavelin_throw.pn‌​g` is real path?

Comment: Thanks Hassan. I have corrected my path. Now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @AbyBasheer I am glad to know it works for you. Please vote up answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the size of an image please use `getimagesize ()` you can read more about this method [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)